# ESP32 crash at boot after adding some code

Tags: crash, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have a strange problem. I have working code which I have used for a long time and did some refactoring moving to use the ArduinoJson library on an ESP32.

My problem now is that by (sometimes) adding any code the ESP32 seems to crash as soon as it boots:

```
16:06:18.253 -> rst:0x3 (SW_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
16:06:18.253 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
16:06:18.253 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
16:06:18.253 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
16:06:18.253 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
16:06:18.253 -> load:0x40078000,len:13260
16:06:18.253 -> load:0x40080400,len:3028
16:06:18.253 -> entry 0x400805e4
16:06:18.681 -> ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

The code added could be a Serial.print("TEST");

I am at the end of my memory, but have been there a long time and at one point was even closer.

```
Sketch uses 1305157 bytes (99%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 56812 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 270868 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

What could the cause be? I have no idea, but it now grinds the project to a halt and it doesn't seem to be the code as no code seems to be executed.

Comment: From Arduino IDE Menu, Choose Tools -> Partition Scheme to pick a scheme for bigger APP memory.